# HFP profile disconnection through Cypress - iOS HFP and PBAP profile both disconnecting at a time

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, hfp, infineon

We have been actively working with Cypress's CYBT413061 Bluetooth module for our project,
we have integrated both HFP and PBAP  profiles in our project .
when a connected device recieved a call,For call audio routing we are disconnecting HFP profile when the call is in ACTIVE state,
but in IOS its disconnecting HFP and also PBAP profile. In Android only HFP is disconnecting                                                                                                               .
We are doing same process for Both Android and IOS. But it is behaving different in IOS and Android .
we are just passing below function to disconnect HFP profile

```
if(handsfree_app_states.state.conn_data.conn_state==WICED_BT_HFP_HF_STATE_SLC_CONNECTED)
{
    wiced_bt_hfp_hf_disconnect(handsfree_ctxt_data.rfcomm_handle);
}
```